# Are we allowed to post excerpts from the 5e D&D playtest?

Tags: discussion

The Online Playtesting Agreement (http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/DNDNextPlaytestingAgreement.pdf) may prohibit excerpting the rules as is common practice on rpg.se:

> You agree not to copy, excerpt, distribute (either in physical or digital 
>   format), publish, display, disseminate, release and/or transmit, in whole or
>    in part, or create derivative materials from any Playtest Materials provided to you...  Notwithstanding the
>   foregoing, you may publicly discuss your thoughts regarding the D&D Next Playtest Materials and your playtesting experience.

I'm not a lawyer, but my reading of this is that we are free to discuss the materials, but not excerpt them here. I would love to be wrong about this, if anyone who is a lawyer and/or has more explicit information from WotC could chime in.

Comment: [**I am not a lawyer and neither do I play on on TV**] I agree with your reading but in doubt either consult your own solicitor or ask Wizards for a clarification.

Comment: http://www.loremaster.org/content.php/267-Protection-from-Chaos-Part-XI-–-The-D-D-Next-Online-Playtest-Agreement discusses what the OPTA asks of play testers and is probably a good guide for anyone posting abou he play test.

Answer (score 13):

Two things.

1. The [clarification provided to ENWorld by WotC](http://www.enworld.org/forum/new-horizons-upcoming-edition-d-d/323569-guidelines-d-d-next-playtest-adventure-discussion-here-enw.html) is that "You can talk about your current and previous playtest experiences and even talk about the rules and mechanics as long as you don’t directly quote text."
2. RPG.SE is not in the business of enforcing miscellaneous contracts. Therefore you might or might not be jeopardizing your own OPTA by posting rules here, but that is not our business and there will be no mod action on posts of this sort.  This is the same approach taken to copyright in general, as we are not lawyers - SE central actions on legal takedown notices but that is it.

Comment: Well said re: contracts. My intention isn't to get SE to go RIAA on everyone, just to prevent people from accidentally getting themselves kicked out of the playtest.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me, like people will just "have to know what you are talking about", and you are correct, that we can not quote the rules or paraphrase them directly.  But we can likely say things like, "the kobold has 2 hitpoints, can the reaper kill them on a miss?"